# htaccess adding country name behind domain name

Tags: php, .htaccess

Anyone tell me how can i redirect my site with country name inserted after domain name with htaccess?
e.g.
http://domain.com/india/
after redirecting new url, my site url will be http://domain.com/india/ in all place where i used link.

Is it possible with htaccess? or I need to do any other way.

I have tried to rewrite with using rewriteRule with query string but it just changed url and will not changed in all places where link should be click.

Following is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 

RewriteRule ^/?$ modules-nct/home-nct/ [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/?$  modules-nct/home-nct/?ccode=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Here ccode is country name like india,US.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but obviously we cannot help you with your code that you say does not work as expected, if you do not share that code with us.

Comment: @C0dekid.php That is not what is asked here.

Comment: Is it possible to have country name in all rules without writing countryname in all rules in htaccess?